# How to add cltr+tap listener to polymer element

Tags: polymer

I would like to create element that does something for `ctrl+tap`. How can I assign listener to it?

I have tried to use `iron-a11y-keys-behavior` https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior
and

```
keyBindings: {
    'ctrl:tap': 'doSomething'
},
```

but it does not work.

Can I use somehow Polymer features like `listeners` or `behaviors` for it, or should I code it on my own using VanillaJS?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is

```
listeners: {
    'tap': '_elementTapped'
},
keyBindings: {
    'ctrl+control:keydown': '_updatePressed',
    'control:keyup': '_updatePressed'
},
_ctrlPressed: false,
_updatePressed: function(event) {
    this._ctrlPressed = event.detail.ctrlKey;
},
_elementTapped: function(){
    if(this._ctrlPressed){
        this.doSomething();
    }
}
```

For me it looks, like an overhead, as we have to add 2 more methods, 1 property and 1 listeners, comparing to `'ctrl:tap': 'doSomething'`.

I would really appreciate cleaner solutions.

Comment: Why do you need the overhead? You can check if `ctrl` was pressed directly in `e.detail.ctrlKey` flag of your tap listener(`_elementTapped`)

Comment: Thanks! I precisely should be `event.detail.sourceEvent.ctrlKey`, but it works.